# Convert two ASCII Hexadecimal Characters (Two ASCII bytes) in one byte

Tags: c, ascii, hex, avr-gcc

I want to convert two ASCII bytes to one hexadecimal byte.
eg.

`0x30 0x43 => 0x0C , 0x34 0x46 => 0x4F` ...

The ASCII bytes are a number between `0` and `9` or a letter between `A` and `F` (upper case only), so between `0x30` ... `0x39` and `0x41` ... `0x46`

I know how "to construct" `0x4F` with the numbers `0x34` and `0x46 : 0x4F = 0x34 * 0x10 + 0x46`

So, in fact, i would to convert one ASCII byte in hexadecimal value.

For that, i can build and array to assign the hexadecimal value to the ASCII char :

```
0x30 => 0x00
0x31 => 0x01
...
0x46 => 0x0F
```

But, maybe it have a most « proper » solution.

The program will be run on an AVR µC and is compiled with `avr-gcc`, so `scanf()` / `printf()` solutions aren't suitable.

Have you got an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: there's no such thing as ASCII bytes or hex bytes.

Comment: What you (apparently!) want to do is **convert** a pair of bytes to a single byte, by **interpreting** the two bytes as ASCII symbols which in turn represent hex digits, and emitting the corresponding hexadecimal value. Solving questions of this sort requires a precise understanding of what you are really doing; and precise communication helps a lot too :) You must be sure you understand, fundamentally, what data is. Like David said, bytes are just bytes; there are no ASCII bytes or hex bytes.

Comment: ASCII byte = byte that represent a ASCII char and hexadecimal byte = byte represented in hexadecimal. I know that bytes are just bytes; I just don't know how to explain it. But others have understood what I meant. Isn't the most important?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i can't make sense of your examples, but if you want to convert a string containing hexadecimal ascii characters to its byte value (e.g. so the string "56" becomes the byte 0x56, you can use this (which assumes your system is using ASCII)

```
uint8_t*
hex_decode(const char *in, size_t len,uint8_t *out)
{
        unsigned int i, t, hn, ln;

        for (t = 0,i = 0; i < len; i+=2,++t) {

                hn = in[i] > '9' ? in[i] - 'A' + 10 : in[i] - '0';
                ln = in[i+1] > '9' ? in[i+1] - 'A' + 10 : in[i+1] - '0';

                out[t] = (hn << 4 ) | ln;
        }

        return out;
}
```

You'd use it like e.g.

```
char x[]="1234";
uint8_t res[2];
hex_decode(x,strlen(x),res);
```

And res (which must be at least half the length of the `in` parameter) now contains the 2 bytes 0x12,0x34

Note also that this code needs the hexadecimal letters A-F to be capital, a-f won't do (and it doesn't do any error checking - so you'll have to pass it valid stuff).

Comment: Use `(in[i]|32)-'a'+10` and now you can support uppercase and lowercase (with just one more instruction in the machine code, most likely).

Comment: Isn't `uint8_t` a byte? Shouldn't that be `uint16_t` if it is supposed to contain two bytes?

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis It's supposed to be a byte, since it contains 1 byte, not 2

Comment: @nos: yes, I see it is an array of uint8_t. Brain fart, sorry.

Comment: Make sure to include cytpe.h

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`strtol()`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#gaf8ce3b8dae3d45c34c3b172de503f7b3), which is part of [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/index.html), or you can write just your specific case pretty easily:

```
unsigned char charToHexDigit(char c)
{
  if (c >= 'A')
    return c - 'A' + 10;
  else
    return c - '0';
}

unsigned char stringToByte(char c[2])
{
  return charToHexDigit(c[0]) * 16 + charToHexDigit(c[1]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, it was so easy ...
I thought to the 4 bits left rotation for the number between 0 to 9 but the solution was even simpler ! Thanks

Comment: It was a joke ? :
$ man ascii
Aucune entrée de manuel pour ascii

Comment: @Loic: No, you must be missing the manual page.  Here's the English version: http://linux.die.net/man/7/ascii

Comment: Is the value being returned from `stringToByte` getting cast to `unsigned char` due to the function being declared as such?

Comment: Yes. Integer promotions make all the arithmetic inside `stringToByte` happen on `int` types, and then the result is returned as an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

The task:

Convert a string containing hexadecimal ascii characters to its byte values
so ascii `"FF"` becomes `0xFF` and ascii `"10" (x31x30x00)` becomes `0x10`

```
char asciiString[]="aaAA12fF";// input ascii hex string 
char result[4];               // byte equivalent of the asciiString (the size should be at half of asciiString[])
```

// the final result should be:

```
result[0] = 0xAA;
result[1] = 0xAA;       
result[2] = 0x12;
result[3] = 0xFF;
```

//1. Firt step: convert asciiString so it contains upper cases only:

```
// convert string to upper cases:
stringToUpperCases(asciiString);
```

use:

```
void stringToUpperCases(char *p)
{   
    for(int i=0; *(p+i) !='\0'; i++)
    {
        *(p+i) = (unsigned char) toupper( *(p+i) );
    }
}
```

//2. Convert a string containing hexadecimal ascii characters to its byte values:

```
// convert string to bytes:

int nrOfBytes = stringToBytes(asciiString,result);

//use:  
unsigned char charToHexDigit(char c)
{
if (c >= 'A')
    return (c - 'A' + 10);
else
    return (c - '0');
}

unsigned char ascii2HexToByte(char *ptr)
{
    return charToHexDigit( *ptr )*16 + charToHexDigit( *(ptr+1) );
}

int stringToBytes(char *string, char *result)
{
    int k=0;
    int strLen = strlen(string);

    for(int i = 0; i < strLen; i = i + 2)
    {
        result[k] = ascii2HexToByte( &string[i] );
        k++;
    }

    return k; // number of bytes in the result array 
}
```

//3. print result:

```
printNrOfBytes(nrOfBytes, result);
```

// use:

```
void printNrOfBytes(int nr, char *p)
{
   for(int i= 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        printf( "0x%02X ", (unsigned char)*(p+i) );
    }
    printf( "\n");
}
```

//4. The result should be:

**0xAA 0xAA 0x12 0xFF**

//5. This is the test program:

```
char asciiString[]="aaAA12fF"; // input ascii hex string 
char result[4];                // result  
// convert string to upper cases:
stringToUpperCases(asciiString);

// convert string to bytes
int nrOfBytes = stringToBytes(asciiString,result);

// print result:
printNrOfBytes(nrOfBytes, result);

// result:
//  0xAA 0xAA 0x12 0xFF
```

Answer (score 0):

It's works, but could be much optimized !

```
inline uint8_t  twoAsciiByteToByte(const std::string& s)
{
    uint8_t r = 0;

    if (s.length() == 4)
    {
        uint8_t a = asciiToByte(s[0]);
        uint8_t b = asciiToByte(s[1]);
        uint8_t c = asciiToByte(s[2]);
        uint8_t d = asciiToByte(s[3]);

        int h = (a * 10 + b);
        int l = (c * 10 + d);

        if (s[0] == '3')
            h -= 30;
        else if (s[0] == '4')
            h -= 31;

        if (s[2] == '3')
            l -= 30;
        else if (s[2] == '4')
            l -= 31;

        r = (h << 4) | l;
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: inline uint8_t asciiToByte(char c)
{

 if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
     return c - '0';

 if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
      return c - 'A' + 10;

 return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that works with both upper and lower-case hex strings:

```
void hex_decode(const char *in, size_t len, uint8_t *out)
{
  unsigned int i, hn, ln;
  char hc, lc;

  memset(out, 0, len);

  for (i = 0; i < 2*len; i += 2) {

    hc = in[i];
    if ('a' <= hc && hc <= 'f') hc = toupper(hc);
    lc = in[i+1];
    if ('a' <= lc && lc <= 'f') lc = toupper(lc);

    hn = hc > '9' ? hc - 'A' + 10 : hc - '0';
    ln = lc > '9' ? lc - 'A' + 10 : lc - '0';

    out[i >> 1] = (hn << 4 ) | ln;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting 2 hex chars to a byte is done in two steps:

1. Convert `char` `a` and `b` to their number (e.g. `'F'` -> `0xF`), which is done in two big if else branches, that check if the char is in the range `'0'` to `'9'`, `'A'` to `'F'` or `'a'` to `'f'`.
2. In the 2nd step the two numbers are joined by shifting `a` (largest value is `0xF` (`0b0000_FFFF`)) `4` to the left (`a << 4` -> `0b1111_0000`) and then apply the bitwise or operation on `a` and `b` (`(a << 4) | b`):

```
a: 0000_1111
b: 1111_0000
-> 1111_1111
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define u8 uint8_t
#define u32 uint32_t

u8 to_hex_digit(char a, char b) {
    u8 result = 0;

    if (a >= 0x30 && a <= 0x39) {
        result = (a - 0x30) << 4;
    } else if (a >= 0x41 && a <= 0x46) {
        result = (a - 0x41 + 10) << 4;
    } else if (a >= 0x61 && a <= 0x7A) {
        result = (a - 0x61 + 10) << 4;
    } else {
        printf("invalid hex digit: '%c'\n", a);
    }

    if (b >= 0x30 && b <= 0x39) {
        result |= b - 0x30;
    } else if (b >= 0x41 && b <= 0x46) {
        result |= b - 0x41 + 10;
    } else if (b >= 0x61 && b <= 0x7A) {
        result |= b - 0x61 + 10;
    } else {
        printf("invalid hex digit: '%c'\n", b);
    }

    return result;
}

u32 main() {
    u8 result = to_hex_digit('F', 'F');
    printf("0x%X (%d)\n", result, result);

    return 0;
}
```