# Convert Ascii number to Hex in C

Tags: c++, c, embedded, hex, ascii

I use the following function to convert a value in hex to ASCII:

```
void hex_to_ascii(unsigned char* buf, unsigned char number)
{
  int i;

  sprintf(  buf, "%03d", number );

  printf("\nNumber in Ascii: ");
  for( i=0; i< 3; i++)
     printf("%#04x ", *(buf+i));

  printf("\n");
  return;
}
```

e.g. If the hex value is `0xff` the function generates `0x32 0x35 0x35` which is the Ascii representation of `255`.

Now I would like to reverse the operation. I would like a function that can be passed three bytes (array of 3) to generate the hex value.

i.e. We pass `0x32 0x35 0x34` and it generates `0xFE.`

Can you please help me with this? It is for an embedded system, the values are not typed they are obtained from a comms buffer.

Many Thanks.

EDIT:

I wrote this and it seems to work..

```
unsigned char ascii_to_hex(unsigned char* buf)
{
   unsigned char hundred, ten, unit, value;

   hundred = (*buf-0x30)*100;
   ten = (*(buf + 1)-0x30)*10;
   unit = *(buf+2)-0x30;     

   value = (hundred + ten + unit);
   printf("\nValue: %#04x \n", value);

   return value; 
}
```

Thanks to everyone for replying.

Comment: You can check [Convert to ASCII String from hex String in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672639/convert-to-ascii-string-from-hex-string-in-c?rq=1) and [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933039/convert-two-ascii-bytes-in-one-hexadecimal-byte?rq=1)

Comment: `number` isn't a "hex value", it's a `char`, i.e. an integer. It doesn't matter whether you call `hex_to_ascii(buffer, 0xFF)`, `hex_to_ascii(buffer, 255)`, or `hex_to_ascii(buffer, 0377)` - they are all the same. The reverse operation is `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use stdlib's atoi() function to convert a string to an integer:

```
char str[] = {0x32, 0x35, 0x34, 0x00};
int integer = atoi(str);
printf("%x\n", integer);
```

you can then printf() that integer as hex/dec or whatever.
If this is too simple for your needs, then a more powerful alternative is to use sscanf()

If you are getting these integer strings from a comms buffer then you will likely want to split the buffer up into separate numbers first (perhaps they are separated by spaces for example). A simple way of doing this in C would be to use strtok().

EDIT:
this edit is in response to the code that you have added to your question. I cannot comment on your question as I do not have enough reputation!
The code you have added is broken. It will only work if a three digit string is provided, eg "001", "255". If a different number of digits are provided, it will read beyond the end of the string and produce garbage output, try "1" or "14", or "12314".

Comment: Note that `atoi()` does not provide any means of adequate error handling. You can use `strtol()` instead, of even `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a number in base10, considering you have all the digits stored in  `char*buf`   like so:

```
//assumtions: n - number of digits
//            digits are ordered MSD first -> buff[0] contains the most significant digit.
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       number += buf[n-i-1]*pow(10,i); //number+=digit*10^i
    }

    printf("%x\n", number);
```